# What do bandages do?

Tags: super-meat-boy

I recently bought the game *Super Meat Boy*, and have noticed there are "bandages" spread out across the world. What do these bandages do? Is it a sort of "score-keeper", or does it have a practical use?

Comment: avestar I think that World Engineer's answer is good so I hope that you could accept it as your best answer

Comment: @DavidToh I asked this question yesterday. :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They [unlock](http://supermeatboy.wikia.com/wiki/Bandages) characters. You unlock one character after 10 bandages and then another for every 20 that you collect beyond that up to 90 and then 10 more gets you the final [unlock](http://supermeatboy.wikia.com/wiki/Unlockable_Characters). The precise characters gained will vary depending on whether you are playing the XBOX version or the PC version.